# Distribute binary iOS frameworks

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods, carthage

Is there any dependency management tool that would allow a third party framework vendor to distribute it's binary without physically providing the framework?

I am looking for something similar to CocoaPods or Carthage, but something that doesn't download / build the source code directly, but rather downloads and links the binary .framework.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure CocoaPods can do this for you, as well as Carthage.

However, I want to point you to another tool, or I's day approach to manage dependencies: it's called [Components](https://github.com/AlexDenisov/Components), here is more details of you still interested: [Components: Taking Step Back from Dependency Management](http://lowlevelbits.org/components-taking-a-step-back-from-dependency-management/).

The basic idea is that for any dependency you have a makefile, everything makefile does is just fetches whatever it needs to bring dependency on developer's machine.

To achieve exactly what you need I can recommend to take a look at, for example, [GoogleAnalytics.make](https://github.com/AlexDenisov/Components/blob/master/Components.make/GoogleAnalytics/3.13.0/GoogleAnalytics.make).

Answer (score 1):

If by `doesn't download / build` you mean `doesn't download & build` then Carthage allows that via binary releases. It's a relatively new feature, but been there for awhile now. Official [documentation](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#archive-prebuilt-frameworks-into-one-zip-file) is very slim on this:

> Carthage can automatically use prebuilt frameworks, instead of building from scratch, if they are attached to a GitHub Release on your project’s repository.
>
> To offer prebuilt frameworks for a specific tag, the binaries for all supported platforms should be zipped up together into one archive, and that archive should be attached to a published Release corresponding to that tag.

You simply place your builds into `/Build/{PLATFORM-NAME}`, zip it up making sure it is named like `{PROJECT-NAME}.framework.zip`, and publish it on GitHub, where `{PLATFORM-NAME}` is `Mac`, 'iOS', etc., and `{PROJECT-NAME}` is your project / repository name.

Check out [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/releases/tag/v4.0.1) for example,  [Quick](https://github.com/Quick/Quick/releases/tag/v0.7.0) also used to do their releases like that, not any longer for some reason.

P.S. The distribution is limited to github only, but I've seen some references saying that zips are supported in general. You can take it from here and if find a way to use other sources, I'd be thankful if you share how it's done for future references.

Comment: I am more interested in setting up a private repository. So if it works only with GitHub, it doesn't really help. However I did some more research into Cocoapods, and it seems that I might be able to use it. Only that I am not sure how the HTTP Authentication will work. Here you can find my latest Stack question related to that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36045520/cocoapods-podspec-source-http-authentication-support

Comment: This question doesn't mention private repositories and is not even related to that. It sounds more like you're trying to avoid source code all together. I've been mostly using Carthage, cannot tell much on CocoaPods side, but in general git authentication works perfectly with ssh keys, which would solve your authentication problem, but you'll probably need to use ssh not http.

Comment: Yes, I try to avoid source code all together but I still want my .framework files to be private (so accessible through some sort of authentication).