# Cocoapods Podspec Source HTTP Authentication Support

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods

I am looking into setting up a private repo that allows distributing binary `.framework` files (so no source code) via Cocoapods.

The actual repo will be hosted on a Git server, just like the Cocoapods page suggests and the actual `.framework` files will be hosted on a different server that would allow accessing the `.framework` files via HTTPs.

Let's say I add this in the .podspec file:

```
spec.source           = { :http => 'https://myhostserver.com/Releases/v1.0.0/MyLibrary.framework.zip' }
```

From reading the documentation it's not clear to me what kind of authentication does Cocoapods support for referencing the `.framework` file via HTTPs.

I had a look at both

http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html
https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#source

Answer (score 2):

CocoaPods' Downloader is using CURL for downloading files under the hood. If you want to use HTTP, you can setup your authentication credentials in the `~/.netrc` file.

Comment: It looks that when CocoPods uses cURL under the hood, it doesn't use the -n option so cURL doesn't use the .netrc file. I have added more details in the GitHub issue I've opened: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5055